# How to delete single data from array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How can I delete one item in an array using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)? I want to delete 1st data using `patientserialno`. I am pushing data like this:

```
BookingJobRequestEntity.push({
  PatientSerialNo: PatientSerialNo, 
  Department_SlNo: Department_SlNo, 
  IsHospitalBooking: IsHospitalBooking, 
  Pickupdate: Pickupdate, 
  Contact_SlNo: Contact_SlNo
});
```

I am having [json](/questions/tagged/json)array like this view:

```
[{
  PatientSerialNo: 1, 
  Department_SlNo: 1, 
  IsHospitalBooking: false, 
  Pickupdate: "01/08/2017", 
  Contact_SlNo: "36"
},
{ 
  PatientSerialNo: 2, 
  Department_SlNo: 1, 
  IsHospitalBooking: false, 
  Pickupdate: "", 
  Contact_SlNo: "36"
},
{
  PatientSerialNo: 3, 
  Department_SlNo: 1, 
  IsHospitalBooking: false, 
  Pickupdate: "",  
  Contact_SlNo: "36"
}]
```

Comment: Um, well you know its an array, right? Why not just loop through the array and call delete obj[i]["Pickupdate"];

Comment: Just FYI there's no such thing as a 'JSON array', it's just a plain old array

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** method, to remove an item, but you need to search for this item index in the array first.

You can also use **[Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** to filter your array data and remove the one with the specified `PatientSerialNo`:

```
BookingJobRequestEntity = BookingJobRequestEntity.filter(function(item){
      return item.PatientSerialNo != 1;
});
```

```js
var BookingJobRequestEntity = [{
    PatientSerialNo: 1,
    Department_SlNo: 1,
    IsHospitalBooking: false,
    Pickupdate: "01/08/2017",
    Contact_SlNo: "36"
  },
  {
    PatientSerialNo: 2,
    Department_SlNo: 1,
    IsHospitalBooking: false,
    Pickupdate: "",
    Contact_SlNo: "36"
  },
  {
    PatientSerialNo: 3,
    Department_SlNo: 1,
    IsHospitalBooking: false,
    Pickupdate: "",
    Contact_SlNo: "36"
  }
]

var arr = BookingJobRequestEntity.filter(function(item){
      return item.PatientSerialNo != 1;
});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

To find an index of an array you could use [Array.findIdex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

> The **`findIndex()`** method returns the index of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise `-1` is returned.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> **callback**: Function to execute on each value in the array, taking three arguments:
>
> **Arguments**:
>
> ***element***: The current element being processed in the array.
>
> ***index***: The index of the current element being processed in the array.
>
> ***array***: The array findIndex was called upon.
>
> **callback**: (Optional). Object to use as this when executing callback.

So, with the given `index`:...

You can use [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) where:

> **Parameters**
>
> ***start***: Index at which to start changing the array (with origin 0). If greater than the length of the array, actual starting index will be set to the length of the array. If negative, will begin that many elements from the end of the array (with origin 1) and will be set to 0 if absolute value is greater than the length of the array.
>
> ***deleteCount*** (Optional): An integer indicating the number of old array elements to remove. If deleteCount is 0, no elements are removed. In this case, you should specify at least one new element. If deleteCount is greater than the number of elements left in the array starting at start, then all of the elements through the end of the array will be deleted.
>
> ***Return value***: An array containing the deleted elements. If only one element is removed, an array of one element is returned. If no elements are removed, an empty array is returned.

e.g:

```
Array.splice(index, 1);
```

Where `index` is the position of the item that you need to remove.

Something like this:

```js
(function() {
  var data = [{
      PatientSerialNo: 1,
      Department_SlNo: 1,
      IsHospitalBooking: false,
      Pickupdate: "01/08/2017",
      Contact_SlNo: "36"
    },
    {
      PatientSerialNo: 2,
      Department_SlNo: 1,
      IsHospitalBooking: false,
      Pickupdate: "",
      Contact_SlNo: "36"
    },
    {
      PatientSerialNo: 3,
      Department_SlNo: 1,
      IsHospitalBooking: false,
      Pickupdate: "",
      Contact_SlNo: "36"
    }
  ];

  function deleteObjectByPatientSerialNo(id) {
    var index = data.findIndex(function(x) {
      return x.PatientSerialNo === id;
    });
    if (index > -1) {
      data.splice(index, 1); // Only remove where the id matches with PatientSerialNo.
    }
    return data; // Returns the array.
  }
  data = deleteObjectByPatientSerialNo(1); // Set the PatientSerialNo to delete.
  console.log(data);
})();
```